# Flutter go_router: push() vs go() and web URL changes

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router

I am facing a use case I don't know the proper way to deal with.

Please see here the simple application I have made: https://dartpad.dev/?id=5a00b315613990d8c3ead6e26bc2df4c

This tries to simulate the typical scenario where you have a record list page with data recovered from a data base, click on one of the records, make some changes and click the "Save" button to go back to the list page and see those changes updated.

If I use `context.push()`, I can see the changes correctly because it returns a Future so I can wait until `context.pop()` is executed in the detail screen and then I run `getDataFromDataBase()` to refresh the data from the database.

The problem I have with using `context.push()` is the URL is not updated when I run this for the web.

If I use `context.go()` instead then the URL is properly updated but since this returns void I cannot properly wait to update the records after `context.pop()`

I feel I am missing something because this must be a very typical scenario. Let's see if you can point me in the right direction:

1. Is it the expected behaviour that `context.push()` doesn't modify the URL?
2. In case I use `context.go()` instead (which by the way seems to be the recommended way to navigate according to the official documentation since imperative navigation can cause some problems: https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/topics/Navigation-topic.html). What's the proper way to manage this scenario? How to update data after `context.pop()`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATM, I'm looking for an answer to your first question myself so I can't answer that.

As for the second one, you can work around it by creating a `Promise`, and pass a function fulfilling that promise into your editing dialog.

Something like this:

```
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      // ...
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          final promise = Completer<bool>();
          context.go('/somePath', extra: promise.complete);
          final editResult = await promise.future;
          // ....
        },
        child: Text('Edit'),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

You can then pick the function up from the `extra`-field in your route, pass it into your dialog and call it when editing is done.

Comment: Thanks @tjarvstrand. Anyway I ended up moving to auto_route package as I found it more convenient for my case. This one updates the URL properly with its core functions. As per the second point, I found it easy to do it through observers to trigger certain operations on push/pop: https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#navigation-observers

Comment: FWIW I found this old issue, so I don't think it's intended behavior: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/115962. I created a new one: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/132430. With regards to auto_router, it seems more convenient, but I don't really trust it. It's unbelievably complex for what it does, code quality is so-so, and documentation about what actually goes on under the hood is non-existent.

Comment: Thanks @tjarvstrand. So it seems it's related to this option: https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/GoRouter/optionURLReflectsImperativeAPIs.html but anyways it's not recommended to set it to true, imperative navigation is strongly discouraged: https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/topics/Navigation-topic.html. We'll try to find a workaround and follow the recommended guidelines. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and use context.push() a lot of times to make sure, my content updates when I navigate back with context.pop(). I tried the solution of @tjarvstrand but the main drawback for me is, that the navigation arrow in the appbar get's lost.

After searching a little bit, I found the following github ticket:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/129893#issuecomment-1617762284

In the migration guide from version 8.0.0 there is a detailed explanation. Just put the following line in your main.dart file and the browser URL is updated:

`GoRouter.optionURLReflectsImperativeAPIs = true;`

In my case I wanted to have clean URLs in my web application, so my main.dart looks like this:

```dart
void main() {
  setPathUrlStrategy(); // see https://pub.dev/packages/url_strategy
  GoRouter.optionURLReflectsImperativeAPIs = true;
  ...
  runApp(MyApp());
```

Thanks to `GoRouter.optionURLReflectsImperativeAPIs = true;` my code for routing can look like this:

```dart
// navigate to another window
onTap: () async {
  var result = await context.push('/my-new-route');
  if (result == true) {
    setState(() {});
  }
},

// and navigate back again
if (context.canPop()) {
  context.pop(true); // 99% case
} else {
  context.go('/'); // if page was called directly this is my fallback url
}
```

and I have the default navigation arrow visible:

[image: Flutter GUI example]

Answer (score 0):

in my case
GoRouter.optionURLReflectsImperativeAPIs = true;
helped me and I am able to see URL changes in the browser

```
Future<void> main() async {

// -->>>>>> place it here
  GoRouter.optionURLReflectsImperativeAPIs = true;

  runApp(
    const MyApp(),
  );
}
```

Hope that will help